# Is the "then" statement of an if statement guaranteed to correspond to the "Not Taken" path of the corresponding branch?

Tags: c++, gcc

For example in this code:

```
if(x) {
    printf("A\n");
}
else {
    printf("B\n");
}
```

The compiler organized the output so that when "x" is true the branch is "not taken" and A executes.
I tried adding `likely` and `unlikely` and this was always the case: the `then` statement always corresponded to `not taken`.

So my question is: Is this always guaranteed to be the case?

My understanding of the `likely` was that it's supposed to give the compiler hints about how to lay things out, so it was ignored in this case since it didn't change the blocks layout and I'm wondering if there's any language guarantee on this or if the compiler decided to ignore the suggestion (or just didn't implement it yet).

Comment: What does "the branch is not taken" mean, specifically?

Comment: You should also include the `[[likely]]` and `[[unlikely]]` case... As well as the definition for `x`.

Comment: Are you asking whether, in the case where `x` evaluates to `true`, the flow always falls through to (in this case) the print A statement as opposed to branching to it? I've never seen that explicitly stated though it seems the compiler would have to go out of its way to not have the code come out like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing at all in the language standard that says anything about how branches are laid out in the compiled machine instructions. Under the as-if rule the compiler can compile the program in any way such that the observable behavior matches one that is permitted on the abstract machine. How branches are laid out in the machine instructions does not affect observable behavior.

The `[[likely]]` and `[[unlikely]]` attributes are only hints to the compiler that the marked path is more or less likely than other paths in the execution flow. It is up to the compiler to decide how or whether at all it uses that information.

So at most this is a quality-of-implementation issue for the compiler if it doesn't lay out the branches in the most performant way, assuming you have optimizations enabled and you are giving the necessary information with `[[likely]]` or `[[unlikely]]`. But maybe the compiler is actually taking that information in consideration but had some other reason to still do a different layout than you expect, e.g. because it may be more efficient of other reasons that the jump instruction. Analyse your specific test case carefully before making assumptions and file a bug report if there is a missed optimization.

Also, make sure that the compiler is set to C++20 or later mode or supports the attributes in previous standard versions as well. They were introduced only in C++20 and attributes that are unsupported should be ignored. Compilers may or may not give a warning in this case.